# ASA 55x - Will management interface shutdown if I remove the IP

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa

I was asked to change the IP address of the management interface on our firewalls but not issue "no ip address" because it will put the interface in shutdown mode which needs to issue no shut again and simply just apply the new ip address. I could not try this to see if it actually happens because it's production environment so here I am. Is that right if I issue no ip address on the management interface, it goes to shutdown mode?

Comment: What IP are you actually connecting to?  If you are using the mgmt0/0 address, then it will drop the session if you clear  or change that address.

Comment: @cpt_fink I get connected to the FW through admin context mgmt interface so dropping session is not an issue here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issuing the `No Ip Address` command **does not** put the interface in a shutdown state. However, I believe your coworker is telling you that your telnet session will be dropped if you issue this command which is correct. Because you would no longer have a management address, you would also no longer have a session using the address set.

If you have to issue the `No Ip address`command, do so from a console connection to avoid losing your session.

Comment: +1 for the: If you have to issue the No Ip addresscommand, do so from a console connection to avoid losing your session. And agree as well - 'no ipaddress' just removes any IP configuration.

Comment: Changing the IP address by issuing a different `ip address x.x.x.x y.y.y.y` command will still drop your session if you are connected to that address.

Comment: Yes, correct. But that other IP address will be reachable for a new session. Whereas issuing the no ip address command will leave you unable to initiate a remote session the mgmt.

Comment: I have an outbound connection to the device, but we use heavy logging so I did not want to cause any disruption for that matter.

Comment: If you're changing the IP address, there will be disruption.